# issues with Debugging Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, debugging, xamarin, memory

when I attempt to debug a Xamarin iOS app for a client, I recieve the following error before debug even starts I am unsure what information here would be relevant. It is a multi-platform app that uses a Shared library and then a shared.windows, a shared.iOS and a shared.Android project.
[image]

Comment: Please do not post errors as images.  And note that the error explicitly tells you to report a bug

Comment: It's an `OutOfMemoryException` for MSBuild. Maybe you can take a look at this case: [Unhandled exception in MSBuild](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/7858), try to switch to the 64-bit MSBuild. For more info you can refer to [Issues of msbuild](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues).